# Can an xperf trace contain passwords?

Tags: windows-7, performance, passwords, privacy, xperf

I recorded an xperf trace. Can the trace contain passwords? (assuming that paths contain no password)

I see that upon hitting `xperf -stop` I have the following warning:

> The trace you have just captured "C:\User.etl" may contain personally identifiable information, including but not necessarily limited to paths to files accessed, paths to registry accessed and process names. Exact information depends on the
>    events that were logged. Please be aware of this when sharing out this trace with other people.

But it's pretty vague.

The commands I used to record the xperf trace are [below](http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3) (given by  [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981)). I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

```
REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" -v DisablePagingExecutive -d 0x1 -t REG_DWORD -f

REM Install the Windows Performance Toolkit (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), open the command prompt with admin rights.

REM Now copy those commands in an empty .CMD file and run the CMD (as admin) before you try to start a program from the startmenu again:

xperf -on BASE+LATENCY+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILENAME+NETWORKTRACE -stackwalk profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread+ProcessCreate+FileCreate+FileCleanup+FileClose+FileRead+FileWrite -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular -f Kernel.etl
xperf -start UserLogger -on Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Core:::'stack'+Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Shwebsvc:::'stack' -BufferSize 2048 -f User.etl

timeout -1

xperf -stop
xperf -stop UserLogger

xperf -merge User.etl kernel.etl SlowShell.etl

del user.etl
del kernel.etl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it never contains the actual data like a memory dump, only the filename or list of processes.